# Error with multiprocessing package

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pygtk

I am trying to use the multiprocessing module within a PyGtk application used to generate a huge report.This application is running on **windows**.

Following is the snippet of code,

```
    p1 = Process(target=self.load_table_1, args=(session))
    p1.start()

   Note: load_table_1 is a select query using SqlAlchemy
```

But it throws an error
On the command prompt I could see an error message,

laucnher.exe: error: no such option: --processing-fork

On the log file a more clear traceback,

```
 File "d:\report_actual\extractors\inputs.py", line 255, in task_function

 File "d:\multiprocessing-2.6.2.1-py2.5-win32.egg\multiprocessing\process.py", line 109, in start

 File "d:\multiprocessing-2.6.2.1-py2.5-win32.egg\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 247, in __init__
```

exceptions.IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

I think multiprocessing module implements an alternative for fork under windows.

Please let me know if i'm missing anything here.

Comment: I'm currently running into a similar problem. Does anyone know a solution to this?